# Delete files except ones created on sundays with in last 4 weeks

Tags: backup, powershell, sql

I have a script that copies some files around and deletes older files from destination. right now it just deletes everything older than 10 days. to increase backup retention we need to keep files that have been copied on Sundays in the last 4 weeks and one latest daily. Please help me, i cant find anything to extract day of the week. this is what i am doing right now

```
Get-ChildItem \\xx\xx\xx\Scripted_SQL_Backup -Recurse | ? {
 -not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt (get-date).adddays(-10)} | remove-item
```

I could run remove-item before the copies kick off, and it'll allow me to keep that nights backup, but how do i delete everything except last 4 sundays?

Comment: Is there any (good) reason you're not using *real backup software* to manage your backups? Artisanal hand-crafted beer is good, artisanal hand-crafted backup programs are generally bad.

Comment: this is what i am looking for but in powershell since i already have one running.
find /path/to/files -type f -mtime +30 \
    -exec sh -c 'test $(date +%a -r "$1") = Mon || echo rm "$1"' -- {} \;

Comment: yes and no. it's not a good reason but i cant do anything about. my goal is to just clear the room, move or vm all boxes in there. owners of that specific box refuse to spend money on it since they know i am charging overhead from my org.

Comment: this is what i came up with ones i was able to extract the day of the week out of the file creation time

Comment: Get-ChildItem c:\test |Select-Object -Property name | Export-csv C:\working\sundaytest.csv
$cleanup=Import-Csv -Path C:\working\sundaytest.csv
foreach ($row in $cleanup)
{
$cleanup_file=$row.name
$cleanup_date=Get-ChildItem C:\test\$cleanup_file | get-date -Format 'dddd'
  if ($cleanup_date -ne "tuesday")
  {
  echo Deleting $cleanup_file
  Remove-Item c:\test\$cleanup_file
  }
  else
  {
  echo Nothing to delete.
  }
}

Comment: does anyone know of a better way of doing this?

Comment: ok, so i realized i was getting modify date, not creation and changed it to this.

Comment: Get-ChildItem c:\test |Select-Object -Property name | Export-csv C:\working\sundaytest.csv
$cleanup=Import-Csv -Path C:\working\sundaytest.csv
"foreach ($row in $cleanup)"
{
$cleanup_file=$row.name
$a = Get-ChildItem c:\test\$cleanup_file | Select-Object CreationTime
$cleanup_date=Get-Date $a.CreationTime -Format 'dddd'

  if ($cleanup_date -ne "monday")
  {
  echo "Deleting $cleanup_file"
  Remove-Item c:\test\$cleanup_file
  }
  else
  {
  echo "Sunday backup $cleanup_file"
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason this doesn't work?

```
$dow = "Sunday"
$weeksToKeep = 4
$path = "\xx\xx\xx\Scripted_SQL_Backup"
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse |
    Where-Object {(($_.LastWriteTime.DayOfWeek -ne $dow) -or ((((Get-Date)-$_.LastWriteTime).TotalDays) -gt ($weeksToKeep*7)))} |
    Remove-Item
```